# Erase the paint drawn on canvas

Tags: java, android, paint

I am developing a paint type app, everything is fine except erase functionality to erase the paint, The erasing code giving a black shadow and I want to remove that so how can I do that.

```
drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

Comment: paint with white/background color?

Comment: thanks but not working, suggest something else